# What is the difference between `a` and `*a` where `a` denotes a 2D array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, syntax

Pointers and arrays are closely associated with each other, so, if we have a 2-D array

```
int a[3][4]={
             1,2,3,4,
             5,6,7,8,
             9,10,11,12};
```

Both

```
printf("%p\n", a);
```

and

```
printf("%p\n", *a);
```

print the same address. What I understand is maybe `a` is pointing to the base address of `a` while `*a` is pointing to the first sub-array of the two-dimensional array `a`.

So, what is the difference between the two?

Comment: Well may be the difference arises when we need to access the different elements of the array rt ?

Comment: Compare `sizeof(a)` to `sizeof(*a)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the declaration

```
int a[3][4];
```

the following are true:

```
Expression     Type            Decays to        Value
----------     ----            ---------        -----
         a     int [3][4]      int (*)[4]       Base address of array
        &a     int (*)[3][4]   n/a              Base address of array
        *a     int [4]         int *            Base address of first subarray
                                                (equivalent to a[0])
      a[i]     int [4]         int *            Base address of i'th subarray
     &a[i]     int (*)[4]      n/a              Base address of i'th subarray
     *a[i]     int             n/a              Value of a[i][0]
   a[i][j]     int             n/a              Value of a[i][j]
  &a[i][j]     int *           n/a              Address of a[i][j]
```

The address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array itself, so the expressions  `a`, `&a`, `*a`, `a[0]`, `&a[0]`, and `&a[0][0]` all yield the same *value* (the address of the first element of the array), but they will have different *types* (`int (*)[3][4]` vs. `int (*)[4]` vs. `int *`).

**Edit**

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

So the expression `*a` is equivalent to `a[0]`; both expressions have type "4-element array of `int`". Since they're not operands of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, those expressions "decay" to type "pointer to `int`".

That's what the "Decays to" column shows.

See section 6.3.2.1 of the [online C 2011 language standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).

Comment: How are we able to see the type of the poimters here ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja: For arrays, it's in the column "Decays to". For pointers, it's in the column "Type".

Comment: Well I understood the fact that though they are pointing to the same address there tyes are different ,But out of teh above types i could get only *a type which is int[4], So it is like pointer to an array but I am not able to ubnderstnad how the other type's would behave ? Can u please provide a source material related to pointer and multidimensional arrays so that i understand it well

Comment: @John Well thanks for source but i am not used to understand these standard documents. It would be helpfull if you could explain in more simpler language :)

Comment: @RohitSaluja: That's about as simple as it gets.  When an array expression such as `a` (3x4 array of `int`) or `*a` (4 element array of `int`) appear in your code, they will be replaced with a pointer expression whose value is the address of the first element, unless the expression is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators.

Answer (score 5):

> What i get is may be a is pointing to the base address of a while *a
>   is pointing to the first sub-array of two-dimensional array a.

That's almost it.

- `a` on its own decays to a pointer (of type `int(*)[3]`) to its first subarray when you pass it to `printf`.
- `*a` designates `a`'s first subarray (of type `int[3]`), and decays to a pointer (of type `int*`) to the first element of that subarray.

In the end, they share the same value because an array has the same address as its first element, recursively.

Comment: **a on its own decays to a pointer to its first subarray when you pass it to printf** ? I didn't get this

Comment: The question is "_What are their differences?_" and not "_How `a` and `*a` points to the same location?_".

Comment: @RohitSaluja array names (such as `a`) decay to a pointer to their first element in all but a handful of contexts. A function call argument is a decaying context.

Comment: @CoolGuy how does the two-bullets comparison of `a` and `*a` not answer the question ?

Comment: For me, the two bullets say the same thing, but in a different way. You've explained the similarities and not the differences.

Comment: @CoolGuy then you read it too fast, or it is poorly worded despite my efforts.

Comment: "_`*a` designates `a`'s first subarray, and decays to a pointer to the first element of that subarray._" -- What?? `*a` is a pointer pointing to `a`'s first subarray. Then you say that it decays; But pointers don't decay.

Comment: @CoolGuy: Sure? In `*a`, `a` itself becomes a pointer to the first sub-array. This pointer gets dereferenced ... I think, Quentin is right.

Comment: @CoolGuy `*a` is not a pointer to the first subarray. It *is* the first subarray (you can think about it as a C++ reference)

Comment: @undur_gongor and Quentin , Ok. That makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

`a` is a 2D array of size 3x4. That means:

- `sizeof(a) == 3*4*sizeof(int)`
- `a[i]` is a 1D array of size 4 (for 0<=i<3)
- `a[i][j]` is an int ( 0<=i<3 and 0<=j<4)
- when used as a pointer `a` decays to `&a[0]`

`*a` is `a[0]`: it is a 1D array of size 4. That means :

- `sizeof(*a) == 4*sizeof(int)`
- `(*a)[i]` is an int (0<=i<4)
- when used as a pointer `*a` decays to `&a[0][0]`

So `a` and `*a` are different objects that decay to pointers to the same address which is also `&a`. But `a` decays to a pointer to `int[4]`, whereas `*a` decays to a pointer to `int` (thanks to  undur_gongor for noticing).

Comment: The last sentence is unclear. Could you please check the grammar?

Comment: "which itself decays to &a[0][0]" -- Are you sure? That would mean that `a + 1` and `*a + 1` are the same. They aren't.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the pointers (that the arrays decay to) is not the address but the type.

As you have seen, both pointers point to the same address. But `a` points to sub-arrays whereas `*a` points to `int`s.

This makes a difference, e.g. when doing address arithmetic. `a + 1` is something different than `*a + 1`.

Comment: I was just wondering about the type. So, `a` is of type `int(*)[3]` and `*a` is an `int*`, right?

Comment: @CoolGuy ...after decaying ;)

Comment: **a is of type int(*)[3] and *a is an int*** so a is a pointer to an array just like we have pointer to integer ? If so then why do we need to use pointers to array ?

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. `*a` is an array of integers. In your case `*a` in nothing but the array `[1,2,3,4]`. Individual elements of this array can be accessed by `(*a)[i]`, where `i` is the index of the required element.

And `a` is pointer to this array of integers. `a[0]` will give you the first array (it is same as `*a`), `a[1]` will give you the second array(which is `[5,6,7,8]`).

For example if you want to access 5th element(which is `5`), it will `a[1][0]`.